# camera countdown timer issue

Tags: objective-c, camera

I have an app which record videos, now I can load the camera, record no problem, issue is i am using the function 
[imagePickerController setVideoMaximumDuration:5];

property which limits the length of the video, what I'm wondering is if there a way this can be a countdown timer on the video screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are unrelated.

Implement an onscreen countdown via whatever means you want and start it when you start the 5 second duration video recording.   Then tear it down when the video stops recording.